# i want an object to have multiple and extensible attributes? how to achieve this using activerecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I need to have an object User which has many attributes. I need to be able to dynamically create and add attributes, and for these easily accessible in the normal way.

What is the best way to achieve this?

For clarity - here's the type of thing i'm trying to create:

```
User.name = "Dave"
User.type = "Admin"
User.height = 12
User.weight = 2
User.favourite_beer = "IPA"

User.name = "Shelly"
User.type = "Admin"
User.height = 12
User.weight = 2
User.favourite_makeup = "Lipstick"
```

This is meant to show that Shelly would have a favourite_makeup wheras Dave would not since it would not apply.

I know that I could simply set favourite_makeup to null in a table - but I don't want to end up with a huge inefficient table since there could be many dozen attributes.

Apologies for the crude example.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try serialize

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html - Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    serialize :preferences, Hash
end

u = User.new
u.preferences[:favourite_beer] = "IPA"
```

Your table would have a text column named preferences or favourites or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the model setup but for a DB setup i'd do something like this:

```
class CreateEntities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :entities do |t|
      t.text :entity

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :entities
  end
end

class CreateAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :attributes do |t|
      t.integer :entity_id
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :attributes
  end
end
```

The idea being that "favourite_beer" and "favourite_makeup" would be entities and then attributes would be where you would associate an entity and a user and hen save a value. This allows you to have many-to-many all around.

From here you'd probably want to make 
USER

```
has_many :attributes
has_many :entities, :through => attributes
```

Entity

```
has_many :attributes
```

Attribute

```
has_many :entities
has_many :users
```

I'm not 100% sure on the models etc but this should be enough to get you started or have someone else come behind and fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this for db or for class?

**DB:**
Create a table for users (ID,Name,etc)
Create a table for attributes definition (ID,attribute,Type)
Create a table for link users with attributes (UserID, AttributeID, Value)

Example:

### *User*

1 | User1
2 | User2

### *Attributes*

1 | Attribute1 | String
2 | Attribute2 | String
3 | Attribute3 | Int

### *UserAttributes*

1 | 1 | Value1
1 | 2 | Value2
2 | 2 | Value3
2 | 3 | Value4

### *Explanation:*

- User1 has Attribute1 with Value1
- User1 has Attribute2 with Value2
- User2 has Attribute2 with Value3
- User2 has Attribute3 with Value4

**Class:**
This is just an idea

```
Public Class User
    Private ReadOnly innerList As Dictionary(Of String, Object)

    Public Default Property Item(index As String) As Object
        Get
            If innerList.ContainsKey(index) Then
                Return innerList(index)
            End If
            Throw New IndexOutOfRangeException
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            If innerList.ContainsKey(index) Then
               innerList(index)=value
            Else
                innerList.Add(index,value)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public sub Add(index As String,value As Object) 
        If innerList.ContainsKey(index) Then
            innerList(index)=value
        Else
            innerList.Add(index,value)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub test
        Dim u1 As new User
        Dim u2 As New User
        u1.Add("attribute1","value1")
        u1.Add("attribute2","value2")
        u2.Add("attribute2","value3")
        u2.Add("attribute3","value4")
        Dim att1 As String=u1("attribute1").ToString
        Dim att3 As String=u2.Item("attribute3").ToString
    End Sub

End Class
```

Hope this help you.